# Правильно вытащить из массива значение и использовать в switch

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток.
Нужно решить одну задачку, но не много запутался.
Нужно, чтобы на определенных страницах отображалась нужная информация, а на всех остальных- другая.
Определенных страниц много, и поочередно записывать их и переключать не правильно.
Попытался использовать массив и вытягивать с оттуда значение, когда находишься на той странице. Но из массива значение не считывает, помогите пожалуйста.

```
$url_request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


$mas_urls = array("/ulr_1","/ulr_2");

if(isset($mas_urls->$url_request)){
    $this_url = true;
}
else{
    $this_url = false;
}
switch ($url_request) {
default:
        if($this_url){
            echo $vibor_url;
        }
        else{
            echo $default_url;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `$this_url = in_array($url_request, $mas_urls)` и `echo $this_url ? $vibor_url : $default_url`  вам в помощь. Или даже их комбинация в виде `$result = in_array($url_request, $mas_urls) ? $vibor_url : $default_url` и `echo $result`.

Comment: спасибо большое!